# Update WebView inside ViewPager after AsyncTask

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have a `WebView` inside a `ViewPager`. When the `WebView` starts to load data, it needs to perform task on some URLs, get some IDs from those URLs and then update the view.

My problem is, how do I update the `WebView` inside the `ViewPager` with the latest content? `ViewPager` is inside a `Fragment`.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_native,
            container, false);

     //.... non-relevant code removed

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(items, activity);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mTwoPane)
                mOnPageSelectedListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

CustomPagerAdapter Class:

```
    private class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Activity activity;
        MyWebView mWebView = null;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(List<Item> items2, Activity activity) {
            this.items = items2;
            this.activity = activity;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            Item item = items.get(position);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detail_screen,
                    container, false);
            mWebView = (MyWebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

            //... Webview settings code removed
            //... Building HTML content removed

            String content = item.content;

            //... Some other HTML Content removed

            html.append(content_prefix);
            html.append(content_test);
            html.append(content);
            html.append(content_postfix);

            html.append(htmlPostfix);

            String htmlString = html.toString();
            htmlString = htmlString.replace("%", "&#37;");

            // At this point the htmlString has HTML data built.
            // This data has some urls, that needs to be parsed to
            // get VideoIDs and it is done by AsyncTask

            // Method that calls AsyncTask
            parseVideoLinks(htmlString);

            mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8",
                    "");

            // ((ViewPager) container).addView((View) view, 0);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView((View) view);

            return view;

        }

        private void parseVideoLinks(String htmlString) {
            UrlTask task = new UrlTask(htmlString);
            task.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }

        public class UrlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            String html = "";

            public UrlTask(String html) {
                this.html = html;
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
                doc.select("img").attr("style", "width:100%")
                        .attr("height", "auto");
                doc.select("iframe").attr("style", "width:100%")
                        .attr("height", "auto");

                Elements paragragh_elements = doc.select("p");
                for (Element element : paragragh_elements) {

                    String text = element.text();

                    if (text != null && !text.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                        if (text.contains("https://www.youtube.com/")
                                || text.contains("http://www.youtube.com/")
                                || text.contains("https://www.youtu.be/")
                                || text.contains("https://youtu.be/")) {

                            String expandedUrl = expandUrl(text);
                            if (expandedUrl != null) {

                                String[] splitUrl = expandedUrl.split("[?&]");

                                for (String split : splitUrl) {

                                    if (split.contains("v=")) {
                                        String videoId = split
                                                .replace("v=", "");

                                        Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "" + videoId);

                                        Element new_element = constructElement(
                                                videoId, text);
                                        element.replaceWith(new_element);

                                    }

                                }
                            } else {
                                // embed

                            }

                        } else {
                            // not a youtube url
                        }

                    }

                }

                return doc.html();
            }

            private Element constructElement(String videoId, String url) {

                Element outerDivElement = new Element(Tag.valueOf("div"), "");
                outerDivElement.attr("style", "position:relative;");

                Element innerDivElement1 = new Element(Tag.valueOf("div"), "");
                Element aElement1 = new Element(Tag.valueOf("a"), "");
                aElement1.attr("href", url);
                Element thumbImgElement = new Element(Tag.valueOf("img"), "");
                thumbImgElement.attr("src",
                        "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/0.jpg")
                        .attr("style", "width:100%;");

                aElement1.appendChild(thumbImgElement);
                innerDivElement1.appendChild(aElement1);

                Element innerDivElement2 = new Element(Tag.valueOf("div"), "");
                innerDivElement2.attr("style",
                        "position:absolute; left:30px; top:30px;");
                Element aElement2 = new Element(Tag.valueOf("a"), "");
                aElement2.attr("href", url);
                Element overlayImgElement = new Element(Tag.valueOf("img"), "");
                overlayImgElement.attr("src",
                        "file:///android_asset/images/play.png").attr("style",
                        "width:130%;");

                aElement2.appendChild(overlayImgElement);
                innerDivElement2.appendChild(aElement2);

                // Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId
                // + "/0.jpg");

                outerDivElement.appendChild(innerDivElement1);
                outerDivElement.appendChild(innerDivElement2);

                return outerDivElement;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

               // At this point, the result has the HTML content
               // that i need to load the webview with.
               // How do set webview data from here..

            }

            public String expandUrl(String shortenedUrl) {
                URL url;
                String expandedURL = "";
                try {
                    url = new URL(shortenedUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
                    httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                    expandedURL = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return expandedURL;
            }

        }

    }
```

How can i set the webview to load data once the asynctask is done, in `onPostExecute()`?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an interface in you async task (and maybe split this out into its own class), for example like the one below;

```
public interface HtmlVideoLinksParsedListener
{
    public void onHtmlVideoLinksParsed(String newHtml)
}
```

and then get your Activity to implement this interface (and the corresponding method) i.e.

```
public class YourActivity implements HtmlVideoLinksParsedListener
{
  //your activity code here

  @Override
  public void onHtmlVideoLinksParsed(String newHtml)
  {
  }
}
```

Then just pass the activity to your Adapter and then in turn to your async task and call the interface method once the HTML is ready to pass back to the webview i.e.

```
public CustomPagerAdapter(List<Item> items2, Activity activity, HtmlVideoLinksParsedListener listener) {
        this.items = items2;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listener;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    private void parseVideoLinks(String htmlString) {
            UrlTask task = new UrlTask(htmlString, listener);
            task.execute();
     }
```

then the Async task ...

```
        //constructor
        public UrlTask(String html, HtmlVideoLinksParsedListener listener) {
            this.html = html;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

               listener.onHtmlVideoLinksParsed(result);

            }
```

Then in your adapter setup a method to add an instance variable with a html String which is used in your instantiateItem() method and called notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter something like this.

```
//in your actvity...

@Override
      public void onHtmlVideoLinksParsed(String newHtml)
      {
           mCustomPagerAdapter.setHtmlString(newHtml);
           mCustomPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

//then in your adapter

//setter 
public setHtmlString(String newHtml)
{
     this.htmlString = newHtml;
}

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      //check for html string and use in web view else do normal processing via async task

      if (htmlString!=null)
      {
         //add new html to webview here
      } else {
         //do normal html processing via async task here

      }
}
```

Hope this helps! :-)